# One man lands on earth or some planet

Tags: story-identification, movie

Movie where one man lands and then walks away. He is among people who are living in hanging houses above watery places. The houses looked really grim and the place looked also grim.  It was shown on British TV a few years ago. I think I watched it in around 2021.  I don’t recall seeing any spaceship.  The people living in the houses looked like humans.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made? Also, when you say "one man lands," I presume you mean he landed in a spaceship of some sort? And did the people living on the planet look like normal humans?

Comment: To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our [guide on asking identification questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/7957).

Comment: This was the ending of Return of the Jedi

Comment: Maybe Time Machine (2002): The people live in houses hanging on cliff faces above a river. Picture of houses: https://pm1.narvii.com/6219/0eb0969007e5c974aabc6bf941bc5812c3c7b430_hq.jpg

Comment: I saw your picture.  It is very similar.  But they were more grim than than your picture.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to speculate that this is *[Waterworld](https://imdb.com/title/tt0114898/)* from 1995.

In the future, sea levels have risen so that oceans cover the Earth, and what few people are still alive live on ramskackle rafts, known as "atolls" because they have a sort of harbor in the center, withe dwelling overlooking it. There's a definite post-apocalyptic "Mad Max feel.

The movie focuses on a single male character, "The Mariner" (played by Kevin Costner), who travels between the atolls.

(Other than the concept, the movie is quite forgettable, so I'm not surprised that you don't remember more details.)

Comment: Here is a picture from *Waterworld* that may ring a bell. https://otakukart.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/waterworld-filmimg.jpg